# Output of a SQL Server Image to PDF

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, pdf

We attempt to display a SQL Server image field as a PDF.  The image displays as a PDF through our main application.  We utilize another web app also for displaying the PDF as needed.

For years, this has worked, however lately there are some, but not all, scanned PDF documents that fail to display properly in the web app even though they display in the main application.  This error seems to occur from new scanners. The message received is: "The file is damaged and could not be repaired."  Below is the code used for rendering the PDF.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
public partial class main : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strConn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OurConnectionString"].ToString();
        string sql = "our_stored_procedure_PDF";
        object image = SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(strConn,CommandType.StoredProcedure,sql,new SqlParameter("@recordid",Request.QueryString["idnum"].ToString()),new SqlParameter("@loc",Request.QueryString["locationID"].ToString()));
        byte[] pdf = null;
        if (image != null && image != DBNull.Value)
        {
            pdf = (byte[])image;
        }
        if (pdf != null)
        {
            long FileSize = pdf.Length;

            long StartPos = 0, EndPos;

            EndPos = pdf.Length;

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();

            String type = "Application/pdf";

            if (String.Empty != type)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = type;
            }

            String Range = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Range"];

            if (null != Range && String.Empty != Range)
            {
                String[] StartEnd = (Range.Substring(Range.LastIndexOf("=") + 1).Split('-'));

                if (StartEnd[0] != null)
                {
                    StartPos = long.Parse(StartEnd[0]);
                }

                if (StartEnd.GetUpperBound(0) >= 1 && null != StartEnd[1])
                {
                    EndPos = long.Parse(StartEnd[1]);
                }
                else
                {
                    EndPos = FileSize - StartPos;
                }

                if (EndPos > FileSize)
                {

                    EndPos = FileSize - StartPos;

                }

                HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 206;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusDescription = "Partial Content";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + StartPos.ToString() + "-" + EndPos.ToString() + "/" + FileSize.ToString());
            }

            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; target=" + "_blank");

            if ((type != String.Empty) && (StartPos != 0))
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = type;
            }
            bool forceDownload = true;
            if (forceDownload) // ' Will cause a download dialog (not using this method for the PDFs)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Order.pdf");
            }

            HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(pdf, (int)StartPos, (int)(StartPos + EndPos));
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        }   
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Problem resolved see below**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- HttpContext.Current.Response.End() was needed after the Flush();

An additional issue (Duplicate Headers) was found when using Chrome though company standard is IE. Commenting out the line for target=_blank and changing the download from attachment to inline resolves the Chrome duplicate header issue.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=Order.pdf");
```